Front door light
I have a light on each side of my front door that looks like the photo below.  It's controlled by a switch in the house that is always on. However the light only turns on at night, either on a timer somehow or by how much light is outside (I have no idea and I asked the previous owner, they don't know either).  I have no idea how this light works.  Also, one of the bulbs needs to be replaced, does anyone know what kind of bulb I need to replace it with, and how to take off this casing?  Apologies but we only recently moved into this house.


Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Also, don't ask multiple questions in one post (such as your implied question about the daylight sensor and the followup about bulb type). See [ask] and take the [tour].

This is what's called a "dusk-to-dawn" light. As @user71659 notes, it's controlled by a sensor in the little nub at the bottom of where it attaches to the house. If you want to force it to be controlled purely by the switch, you could probably cover the sensor with opaque tape.
Looking at the bulb, it appears to be a standard A19 bulb; almost any A19 bulb rated for use in enclosed spaces should do as a replacement.
As far as opening up the fixture to get at the bulb, I would assume that either the whole top twists off or there'll be one or more screws in the top which can be loosened or removed to allow one or more of the glass panels to swing open like a door.

Super helpful, thank you! And apologies to all here for not formatting my question properly.

Some of these types of lights also have a small switch that can be used to change its behavior from dusk-to-dawn to always on.  To change the bulb, there may be screws at the corners of the hexagonal lid, or you just rotate the big pointy thing on top.

Found the screws and found the bulb type. Thank you!

Answering the first question: There's an ambient light sensing photodiode. It's the bottom facing nub on the cylindrical base. It should turn on at dusk and switch off at sunrise when the indoor switch is on. It looks like it needs a clean with a wet cloth.
